# Freemarker не видит передаваемые данные

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

Доброго времени суток.

**Описание проблемы:**
Имеется html шаблон описанный с помощью freemarker (ниже представлена часть шаблона):

```
<#list products as product>
    <tr data-productId="${product.id}">
        <td>
            <input size="40" value="${product.name}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="40" value="${product.quantity}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="40" value="${product.price}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="40" value="${product.discount}"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button>Удалить</button>
         </td>
     </tr>
</#list>
```

Заполняется этот шаблон из контролера (Spring MVC) таким образом:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/products/init")
public String initProductsStoragePage(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
    workLogger.info("GET /products/init");

    ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList<>();
    model.addAttribute("products", list);

    return "storageProducts";
}
```

При заполнении шаблона получаю исключение:

> freemarker.log._JULLoggerFactory$JULLogger.error Error executing FreeMarker template
> FreeMarker template error:
> The following has evaluated to null or missing:
> ==> products  [in template "storageProducts.ftl" at line 25, column 20]

(В ошибке речь идет о строчке `<#list products as product>`, а именно о переменной products)

Версия Spring - 5.2.11.RELEASE

Версия Freemarker - 2.3.30

**Вопрос:** если я правильно понял, freemarker жалуется, что products является null или забыли передать атрибут с таким именем. Однако, как видно из кода контролера, такой сценарий исключается. Пожалуйста, скажите в чем может быть причина ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема может возникать если допущена ошибка в указании пути для сканирования ViewResolver. К примеру, если используете конфигурационный класс спринга, проверьте путь в аннотации @ComponentScan. Папка с темплейтами должна быть поддиректорией этого пути.